# How to create and "layer" texture nodes into one material?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, camera, texture-coordinates

Hello guys how are yall?
I edited this plot bc the question I posted week earlier seems kinda impossible to solve but I kinda figure this is easy to recreate it so i wont have to ask a duplicate,lemme try again.

so hey! this the texture I want to recreate, cute i know.
[image: texture]

this texture is composed of two layers or materials or what you like to call
The first layer is the shadeless base which the spherical gradient from white to green like this
[image: shadeless]

the other layer is the shade aka the dark green part of the texture

so I have already know how to recreate the first layer (shadeless base) but I'm struggling to remake tbhe second layer (the shade) and thing is the shade must take the curve of the object facing the camera like the texture i gave (like a fresnel) the shade looks oval bc its on a sphere, for spherical objects like the model im gonna listed down, see the linked picture in the next paragraph(focus on the green figure)

it should be noted the shade is not centered but rather mid-down like this [pic](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/821417163847106585/886310755190833152/look1_ar.png) (focus on the head of the yellow figure)

so first mini questions whats the best way to make the shade?

now whens that solves, how can i layer them into one material without effecting the colors of the texture

also here's the blend File if yall intrested

[image]

Thanks in advance and sorry for editing the old post

and Happy Bl!

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing the differences.  But what you're doing here is basically sphere mapping, the same as a matcap.  Have you tried setting your vector transform to "normal" mode rather than "point"?  The mapping won't change with camera or character translation once you do that.

Comment: Hey @Nathan ! thank you answering, sorry if I wasnt clear abt the difference but I already edit the pose so you can see it better, also the "normal"  mode didnt work for me sadly

Comment: With the material and camera settings you're showing I'm unable to replicate your results.  Using a grid pattern composited with your image in GIMP I can see distortion, but don't know what's causing it.  It might be helpful if you included the blend file in your ask, or a a truncated version of the blend file that has the problem, and any needed image textures packed. The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files: blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: Hello @KickAir8p , the reason the texture is distorting is the prespective, to be exact spherically distorted, I think I might know the solution but I don't know the way to solve it. I think I can take the texture coordinates and flatten out the depth or one of the axis or thats at least what I think, maybe using camera data or something like that to do the job? (also is it ok to send the blend privately?)

Comment: Your question and the answer/s aren't just for you, they're for everyone who has similar problems to look up -- so, no, the blend file should be part of your ask for anyone to download later (as will .blends in any answers).  If there's something you shouldn't share, either remove it or replace it with something generic (I tested on a few roundcubes, some elongated into torso'n'arm shapes).  If the problem doesn't happen on your generic test objects, that'll be a big clue right there.

Comment: Hello @KickAir8p amny apologize for the last comment, here's the blend file

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=WDzm8R8j" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/WDzm8R8j/)

Comment: The image you're using isn't packed into the .blend, but since you included it your ask I grabbed that one.  I think the problem I was having was I didn't get in all your camera settings -- using your camera I can replicate the problem.  Pls see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Turns out there is a solution for the old question and it was simple as hell ~facepalms~

anyways here's what I did:
first I change the render engine into workbench...then imported the texture image as a matcap[image: ok]
and pretty much thats it

and the good news it doesn't effect by the prespective so thats a win , [look at this](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/860128363570003968/980097971372826664/720_30_4.77_May282022_001_1.gif)

and boom look at this beauty
[image: final]

now all I need to do is tweak the texture to get the results i want but right now Im happy with the solution

Also thanks to everyone who helped me and happy Bl!

EDIT:
after few thoughts, I want to make the matcap into a material instead bc I used to EEVEE engine more so I found this nice guy [node setup](https://www.blendernation.com/2020/08/27/matcaps-in-eevee-new-method/) for using matcap in EEVEE and the results is beautifully accurate for me.

now I cropped the image texture earlier to fit the texture better and I tried again and its beautiful.

now I tried with another texture (a golden one) cropped and use it on the eevee setup...added a white outline via Outline Helper addon (and glow was done on photoshop) and now look at this beauty.
[image: gold]

Comment: I don't know why the render looks dark tho its not in my studio but im still amazed by this simple solution  

Comment: So the answer was from @Nathan 's first comment, matcap. His idea was to replicate matcap settings in a material, but the answer was to use it as a matcap.

Comment: yes, I doubt that at first bc I need to replicate the texture, but by the look of image again, the texture is already matcap, even tho im eager to find a way to make the matcap into a material not bc simplicity in handling with texture but also I want to have the body and the heady different portions of the gradient; I can try try that with normal nodes but still I may stick with workbenches and im pretty happy w8 the results.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes I composited a grid with your image and added some roundcubes:

[image]

In your current setup the camera is over a meter below your figure's head, so it's looking up at it.  When in Orthographic this doesn't matter, but when you use Perspective this will make the texture appear to be higher on your figure's head:

[image]

Raising the Z-height of the perspective camera to be level with your figure's head helps, so long as the Location Y-mapping of the material is also adjusted:

[image]

(Screenshots composited to simultaneously show camera info and material settings.)

Although this should answer your question, I'm uncertain how usable it'll be for your purpose.  You might want to edit your question with anything relevant that I haven't addressed and see if someone else comes up with better.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I think I get the idea however the distortion doenst apply on y axis but also on X axis too, I can always center the model but it will work too right?

Comment: sorry for commenting again, but someone told me to remake the texture woth materials...even tho the gradient is achievable with this [shadless head](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/821417163847106585/978734552073789501/shadelesshead.png) its the shadding (the dark green) i might get struggle with, how to get it? based on camera or the object itself?

Comment: The distortion is (IMHO) very subtle and difficult to see clearly enough to test, that's why I added a grid to the texture.  What I've posted in my answer is as far as my knowledge and abilities will go on this, hopefully someone with more relevant skills can help.

Comment: hello @KickAir8p sorry for late response, I tried the blend you gave me and it sadly didnt work but however I think i have kinda a solution but i dont know how to execute that, i edited the post into a different question, sorry abt that but thanks again for the help